# Can't connect to my server using remote desktop connection

Tags: windows-server-2008, remote-desktop, port-forwarding, windows-sbs

When I try to communicate with my server using remote desktop from my home computer I get following message:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/smInJ.jpg

But when I go to work, and use any computer in my work network, I connect to my server using remote desktop without any problem. I looked up to my router settings and port forwarding is ***Port 3389 ->to my server IP address.***

Any idea what might problem can be?

Comment: Did you check your firewall logs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I looked up to my router settings and port forwarding is Port 3389 ->to my server IP address.

When you say `"my router"` do you mean your home router? If so, you shouldn't have to do this.

Is your server behind a hardware or software firewall? If so, *that's* where you have to open 3389.

Comment: Before my server there is router, and there is port forwarding directly to my server IP adress. I have software firewall, and I will try to open 3389 port there. Thx for answer!

Comment: Yes, in my firewall options, 3389 port was not blocked but it was allowed only to private IP addresses network range. Thx

Comment: @Mr.M If this answered your question, you should click on the check next to my answer to accept it as correct.

Answer (score 0):

Actually if you can connected from anywhere, it means no problem with your server. Problem is have you allow from specific ip address in your router at your server network ?
Logic : your router have allowed to port 3389 from your ip public office, so you must allowed from home ip public too.